# SpringValidatorAdapter bug? Validating collection of Strings

Tags: spring-boot, validation

Say that our http request data are:

```
{
  "a": ["a", "b", "c"]
}
```

corresponding DTO could be:

```java
    @Data //lombok
    public class DTO {
        private List<String> a;
    }
```

but we want to validate this as well, including elements in collection, which should be possible with Java Bean Validation 2.0 and (IIRC) from hibernate-validator 6.0.1. So lets add annotations:

```java
    @Data
    public class DTO {
        @NotEmpty
        private List<@NotBlank String> a;
    }
```

however, this does not work neither in our "2.2.2.RELEASE" nor in newest "2.3.0.RELEASE".

This method: `org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter#processConstraintViolations` will correctly receive ConstraintViolation(below is its toString):

```
ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must not be blank', propertyPath=a[0].<list element>, rootBeanClass=class DTO, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank.message}'}
```

so it means that hibernate-validator is OK, however it continues with with its logic, and calculates field related to this error to be: `a[0]`. When we drill deeper, we can find org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults#getPropertyDescriptor trying to find propertyDescriptor named "a" or "A" failing to find it. I thought it might be caused by used lombok, so I added setters/getters manually, but no change. Full delombok did not help either, and this is all I can do to help with PropertyDescriptors. Everything what could be searched for is in the class declared.

Is it a bug? Do I have something set incorrectly? Does SpringBoot need some help to be able to process such bean validation?

Produced exception:

```java
    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: JSR-303 validated property 'a[0]' does not have a corresponding accessor for Spring data binding - check your DataBinder's configuration (bean property versus direct field access)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at brave.servlet.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:65)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:204)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.ExceptionLoggingFilter.doFilter(ExceptionLoggingFilter.java:50)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at brave.servlet.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:82)
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.LazyTracingFilter.doFilter(TraceWebServletAutoConfiguration.java:138)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JSR-303 validated property 'a[0]' does not have a corresponding accessor for Spring data binding - check your DataBinder's configuration (bean property versus direct field access)
        at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.processConstraintViolations(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:188)
        at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:109)
        at org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils.invokeValidator(ValidationUtils.java:89)
        at org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils.invokeValidator(ValidationUtils.java:56)
        at ...our code...
        at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:892)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.validateIfApplicable(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:266)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:137)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:167)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        ... 87 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'a[0]' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'a[0]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:622)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:612)
        at org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:104)
        at org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getRawFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:284)
        at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.getRejectedValue(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:318)
        at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.processConstraintViolations(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:174)
        ... 104 common frames omitted
```

Expected behavior — as any other bean validation issue.

**UPDATE** — so definitely not a bug. I created "same" field in different DTO being processed via different, but equally annotated, controller, and it works. Placement into different modules also does not seem to produce different result. I'll retry lombok. So far I have no idea why it fails.

**UPDATE** — I think I found some clue:

if I have controller method defined as this:

`public void accept(@RequestBody @Valid DTO dtos) {`

it works just fine. However if I have it like this:

`public void accept(@RequestBody @Valid List<DTO> dtos) {`

if fails as described. By default this is not validated, sure. What we have here to enable this validations are these 2 classes:

```java
    @ControllerAdvice
    public class ValidatorAdvice {

        private final LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator;

        @SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaInjectionPointsAutowiringInspection")
        public ValidatorAdvice(LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator) {
            this.validator = validator;
        }


        /**
         * Adds the {@link CollectionValidator} to the supplied
         * {@link WebDataBinder}
         *
         * @param binder web data binder.
         */
        @InitBinder
        public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
            if (binder.getTarget() instanceof Collection) {
                binder.addValidators(new CollectionValidator(validator));
            }
        }
    }
```

and

```java
    import java.util.Collection;

    import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
    import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
    import org.springframework.validation.Validator;
    import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean;

    public class CollectionValidator implements Validator {

        private final Validator validator;

        public CollectionValidator(LocalValidatorFactoryBean validatorFactory) {
            this.validator = validatorFactory;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
            return Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
        }

        /**
         * Validate each element inside the supplied {@link Collection}.
         *
         * The supplied errors instance is used to report the validation errors.
         *
         * @param target the collection that is to be validated
         * @param errors contextual state about the validation process
         */
        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
            Collection collection = (Collection) target;
            for (Object object : collection) {
                ValidationUtils.invokeValidator(validator, object, errors);
            }
        }
    }
```

these will do the validation of all DTO in dto list (`@RequestBody @Valid List<DTO> dtos`), but somehow it messes with the validation. Any ideas why is it like this, or how to do it correctly (if this is incorrect way)?

Comment: I honestly don't have a clue what your question is. What doesn't work? The validation messages? Validation in general? I honestly don't know.

Comment: my bad, will update. Need to generate stacktrace again. Meanwhile: the code fails with NotReadablePropertyException, instead with normal complaint, that a[0] must not be blank

Comment: Please add the error you get as well as the actual code you are using (looks like you added some code to the question that looks like your code but isn't).

Comment: I updated the text removing the incorrectly named referenced field (productCode[0]), but it is really just a name. The point is SpringValidatorAdapter cannot process ConstraintViolationImpl instance. This one is generated OK, from which I suppose, our code is fine.

Comment: I probably found somehting which influences the issue, @M.Deinum if you can take a peek at last update, it would be great. I hope it will give you all detail you need.

Comment: Have you tried `List<@Valid Dto> your list` in the signature and without your own dedicated advice/validator?

Comment: Thanks for help, this one helped. Somehow I didn't get the memo, that this is now possible, it didn't ring any bell even when I was writing @NotBlank type annotation. I had to change exception handlers etc. but now it works. I'm still little bit surprised, that this led to not very easy-to-consume exception, but some lessons are harder I suppose. Thanks for help.